# github Merge is blocked even after successful deployment

Tags: github, github-actions

We have a few branch policies to protect one of the branches in the github repo. One policy is that the deployment to the specified environment must be successful. But even after the deployment is successful on the specified branch, github blocks the merge saying the deployment is missing.

Here is the snapshot of the github checks:

[image: Github status checks]

As the first block says, the branch was successfully deployed into the environment. But github still blocks my merge.

Is there something blatant that I am missing. Any help is appreciated, thanks!

I am expecting that there is no blocker to my branch, since the deployment to the specified environment was successful.

Comment: Is the name of the environment that was successfully deployed to correct? The screenshot doesn't show it.

Comment: Yes, there is just one environment in this particular repo.

Comment: And does it have the correct name?

Comment: Yes, the names are correct.

Comment: @AdhityaRavi did you ever find the root cause of this? I currently have this issue as well.

Comment: unfortunately, never solved this